# Retrieve values submitted via HTML form using parse.com backend

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to Retrieve values submitted via HTML form using parse.com backend and render the values in a template.
I have tried the following:

HTML Form

```
<form action='/hello' method = 'GET'>
                <input id = 'myNumber' name= 'myNumber' type="number" value="100">
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
                    <br>
                Last name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
                    <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Code on Parse.com (app.js) to obtain, first name from the submitted form and render in the HTML.

```
    app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.params);  // returns a empty array in Parse.com app log
      console.log(req.params.firstname); // returns 'No Message Provided' in Parse.com app log
      res.render('hello', { message: req.params.firstname }); // Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

    });
```

Could someone please guide me to render form values in a HTML page.